# mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli / NULL with included functions PHPUnit

Tags: php, mysqli

I ran into an issue:
mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli //PHP 5

OR

> Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null // PHP 7

Seems like MySQL is not defined, I have no idea why so here is my Setup:

config.php contains:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "");
?>
```

functions.php Includes the config.php and contains the function I want to call

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

function check($server_id,$user_id) {
  global $mysqli;

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"); // <-- ERROR
......
}
```

And this is my PHPUnit Testclass

```
<?php

include 'functions.php';

class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testCheck() {
        $this->assertEquals(check(8,3),0);
    }
}

?>
```

Well mysqli is defined in class test, since I have a check before that.
And the Global worked before fine.
So do you have an idea why it breaks?

Comment: Try `var_dump($mysqli);` to see if something is wrong with the `$mysqli` variable

Comment: I have this Function 2 Times in the PHP Script, the Second Time calling it runs into this Server. The First run contains a valid mysqli object, the second Time the Object is null.

Comment: It's most likely because you close the connection somewhere.